# How to stop function with pygame in it while the program keeps running

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, keyboard

So I made a tic tac toe game (with youtube video) and I'm using a hotkey to start the tic tac toe game but when I try to stop the tic tac toe function the open window says no respose and then I have to force quit the window btw when I want to stop the function I want the program to keep running plz help.

```
import keyboard
import time
import pyautogui as pg
import pygame
import numpy as np

hotkeyt = "ctrl+alt+t"

def tic_tac_toe():
    # initializes pygame
    pygame.init()

    # ---------
    # CONSTANTS
    # ---------
    WIDTH = 600
    HEIGHT = WIDTH
    LINE_WIDTH = 15
    WIN_LINE_WIDTH = 15
    BOARD_ROWS = 3
    BOARD_COLS = 3
    SQUARE_SIZE = WIDTH//BOARD_COLS
    CIRCLE_RADIUS = SQUARE_SIZE//3
    CIRCLE_WIDTH = 15
    CROSS_WIDTH = 25
    SPACE = SQUARE_SIZE//4
    # rgb: red green blue
    RED = (255, 0, 0)
    BG_COLOR = (28, 170, 156)
    LINE_COLOR = (23, 145, 135)
    CIRCLE_COLOR = (239, 231, 200)
    CROSS_COLOR = (66, 66, 66)

    # ------
    # SCREEN
    # ------
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (WIDTH, HEIGHT) )
    pygame.display.set_caption( 'TIC TAC TOE' )
    screen.fill( BG_COLOR )

    # -------------
    # CONSOLE BOARD
    # -------------
    board = np.zeros( (BOARD_ROWS, BOARD_COLS) )

    # ---------
    # FUNCTIONS
    # ---------
    def draw_lines():
        # 1 horizontal
        pygame.draw.line( screen, LINE_COLOR, (0, SQUARE_SIZE), (WIDTH, SQUARE_SIZE), LINE_WIDTH )
        # 2 horizontal
        pygame.draw.line( screen, LINE_COLOR, (0, 2 * SQUARE_SIZE), (WIDTH, 2 * SQUARE_SIZE), LINE_WIDTH )

        # 1 vertical
        pygame.draw.line( screen, LINE_COLOR, (SQUARE_SIZE, 0), (SQUARE_SIZE, HEIGHT), LINE_WIDTH )
        # 2 vertical
        pygame.draw.line( screen, LINE_COLOR, (2 * SQUARE_SIZE, 0), (2 * SQUARE_SIZE, HEIGHT), LINE_WIDTH )

    def draw_figures():
        for row in range(BOARD_ROWS):
            for col in range(BOARD_COLS):
                if board[row][col] == 1:
                    pygame.draw.circle( screen, CIRCLE_COLOR, (int( col * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE//2 ), int( row * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE//2 )), CIRCLE_RADIUS, CIRCLE_WIDTH )
                elif board[row][col] == 2:
                    pygame.draw.line( screen, CROSS_COLOR, (col * SQUARE_SIZE + SPACE, row * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE - SPACE), (col * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE - SPACE, row * SQUARE_SIZE + SPACE), CROSS_WIDTH )    
                    pygame.draw.line( screen, CROSS_COLOR, (col * SQUARE_SIZE + SPACE, row * SQUARE_SIZE + SPACE), (col * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE - SPACE, row * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE - SPACE), CROSS_WIDTH )

    def mark_square(row, col, player):
        board[row][col] = player

    def available_square(row, col):
        return board[row][col] == 0
        return True

    def check_win(player):
        # vertical win check
        for col in range(BOARD_COLS):
            if board[0][col] == player and board[1][col] == player and board[2][col] == player:
                draw_vertical_winning_line(col, player)
                return True

        # horizontal win check
        for row in range(BOARD_ROWS):
            if board[row][0] == player and board[row][1] == player and board[row][2] == player:
                draw_horizontal_winning_line(row, player)
                return True

        # asc diagonal win check
        if board[2][0] == player and board[1][1] == player and board[0][2] == player:
            draw_asc_diagonal(player)
            return True

        # desc diagonal win chek
        if board[0][0] == player and board[1][1] == player and board[2][2] == player:
            draw_desc_diagonal(player)
            return True

        return False

    def draw_vertical_winning_line(col, player):
        posX = col * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE//2

        if player == 1:
            color = CIRCLE_COLOR
        elif player == 2:
            color = CROSS_COLOR

        pygame.draw.line( screen, color, (posX, 15), (posX, HEIGHT - 15), LINE_WIDTH )

    def draw_horizontal_winning_line(row, player):
        posY = row * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE//2

        if player == 1:
            color = CIRCLE_COLOR
        elif player == 2:
            color = CROSS_COLOR

        pygame.draw.line( screen, color, (15, posY), (WIDTH - 15, posY), WIN_LINE_WIDTH )

    def draw_asc_diagonal(player):
        if player == 1:
            color = CIRCLE_COLOR
        elif player == 2:
            color = CROSS_COLOR

        pygame.draw.line( screen, color, (15, HEIGHT - 15), (WIDTH - 15, 15), WIN_LINE_WIDTH )

    def draw_desc_diagonal(player):
        if player == 1:
            color = CIRCLE_COLOR
        elif player == 2:
            color = CROSS_COLOR

        pygame.draw.line( screen, color, (15, 15), (WIDTH - 15, HEIGHT - 15), WIN_LINE_WIDTH )

    def restart():
        screen.fill( BG_COLOR )
        draw_lines()
        for row in range(BOARD_ROWS):
            for col in range(BOARD_COLS):
                board[row][col] = 0

    draw_lines()

    # ---------
    # VARIABLES
    # ---------
    time.sleep(0.25)
    pg.hotkey("alt", "shift", "tab")
    player = 1
    game_over = False
    running = True
    # --------
    # MAINLOOP
    # --------
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
                break

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and not game_over:

                mouseX = event.pos[0] # x
                mouseY = event.pos[1] # y

                clicked_row = int(mouseY // SQUARE_SIZE)
                clicked_col = int(mouseX // SQUARE_SIZE)

                if available_square( clicked_row, clicked_col ):

                    mark_square( clicked_row, clicked_col, player )
                    if check_win( player ):
                        game_over = True
                    player = player % 2 + 1

                    draw_figures()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                    restart()
                    player = 1
                    game_over = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    running = False
                    break


        pygame.display.update()

while True:
    while keyboard.is_pressed(hotkeyt):
        tic_tac_toe()
        break
```

I try to stop the funciton with this

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
        break
```

Comment: You're suspending your main game loop, including event checks and display update. That's why the window freezes. What exactly do you want to control with your hotkey?

Comment: I want to be able to open tic tac toe with a hotkey while the program is running in the back ground.

Comment: Your program won't be able to respond to input if it's not the active window so you can't really run it in the background (of other windows). Only the OS/desktop manager can do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
or event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
        break
```

By this you are stopping the whole program. Instead make a separate function and when the hotkeys are pressed, make the function stop.